# How do I implement SAML 2.0 in a WCF Client?

Tags: wcf, saml

I need to implement SAML 2.0 for a WCF client that is talking to a java web service (Glassfish).  I know very little about SAML, and after a bit of searching here (and elsewhere) I do not find much about how to implement with WCF.  Since WCF abstracts you away from the SOAP layer how can I add SAML assertions to the SOAP header?  Will a 3rd party tool like ComponentSpace work best?  Or should I roll my own?  Other advice?

Comment: anyone?  I need to add the wse:security stuff in the soap header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use this [SAML Toolkit for ASP.NET](http://www.componentsoft.net/component/saml.net/). The setup package includes several sample projects which help you to get started quickly.